# What is the meaning of "available RAM" for calculating MySQL max_connections

Tags: mysql, max-connections

The question was asked previously, "how do I calculate MySQL max_connections" and this was the answer:

> max_connections = (Available RAM - Global Buffers) / Thread Buffers

Since I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to the existing question I had to ask a brand new question.

I can get the buffer values by executing : `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%'`; but what is the available RAM part of this equation exactly?

Is this value in bytes, kilobytes, megabytes?  Something else?  Also, do I use the available RAM shown in the resource monitor while my site is being used, or do I need to use the total amount of RAM installed on the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say 'Available RAM' means max memory mysql can claim. And 'Global buffers' would mean buffers like `innodb_buffer_pool`, `key_buffer_size`, `query_cache_size`, etc.

Comment: So in what format do I plug the available ram into the formula?  Bytes, kilobytes, megabytes?  Something else?

Comment: As long as you are consistent with the unit, you should arrive at same result. I'd go for MB.

Answer (score 0):

At this time you can use mysqlcalculator.com to assist with determining your RAM footprint in about 2 minutes if you have your SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; list available.

Answer (score 0):

The default of 151 is a reasonable starting point.  After running for some time, you may, but probably won't, see any problems.  If you do have problems, any of several things could need tweaking -- including indexes on tables.  `max_connections` rarely needs tweaking.

Bottom line:  Don't fret over that one settings.

Answer (score 0):

Hi When I give the values in the above formula, I am getting -ve DB Connections kindly adivice. Using 5.7 mysql

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).